# remove all binary files recursively from git repo and commit history

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have read a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740187/git-how-to-remove-file-from-historical-commit) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854810/cleaning-up-git-history) [threads](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) on removing large binary files from git commit history, but my problem is just a little bit different. Hence my question here to understand and confirm the steps--

My git repo is `~/foo`. I want to remove all *.jpg, *.png, *.mp4, *.ogv (and so on) from one of the directories inside the repo, specifically from `~/foo/public/data`.

#### Step 1. Remove the files

```
~/foo/data > find -E . -regex ".*\.(jpg|png|mp4|m4v|ogv|webm)" \
    -exec git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
    'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch {}' \
    --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all \;
```

#### Step 2. Add the binary file extensions to .gitignore and commit .gitignore

```
~/foo/data > cd ..
~/foo > git add .gitignore
~/foo > git commit -m "added binary files to .gitignore"
```

#### Step 3. Push everything

```
~/foo > git push origin master --force
```

Am I on the right track above? I want to measure twice before I cut once, so to say.

**Update:** Well, the above gives me the error

```
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
..
```

So I went up the tree to the top level and re-ran the command, and it all worked.

Comment: I was going to use this method with `find`, but it re-runs the `filter-branch` on every commit and branch for every file.  In my case, that would've been over 16,000 times! What worked for me was `git rm -r` and just specifying the name of the directory containing the offending files... ``git filter-branch --force --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/image/files' -d /cygdrive/r/git-rewrite_`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%z"` --tag-name-filter cat -- --all``

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I have updated my 2013 answer with a 2020 tool.

Answer (score 10):

The process seems right.

You can also test your clean process with a [tool like bfg repo cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15924054/6309):

```
java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files *.{jpg,png,mp4,m4v,ogv,webm} ${bare-repo-dir};
```

(Except BFG makes sure it doesn't delete anything in your latest commit, so you need to remove those files in the current index and make a "clean" commit. All other previous commits will be cleaned by BFG)

Update 2020: for removing files, you would now use **[`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)** (Git 2.22+, Q4 2019), since [`git filter-branch` or `BFG` are now, 7 years later, obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

```
git filter-repo --path fileToRemove --invert-paths
```

Comment: The BFG is likely a good tool for the job (disclaimer: I'm the creator of The BFG) - I just want to clarify that it does a similar job to `git-filter-branch`, so it would probably _replace_ the script in Step 1 (rather than 'test' it). The BFG acts over the entire repo however, and currently can not be restricted to a single folder path like `~/foo/public/data`. If files with those extensions don't exist elsewhere in the repo, then that's not a problem. Alternatively, if they *do* exist, but are in protected commits (eg your `HEAD` commit) then they won't be deleted either.

Comment: @RobertoTyley thank you for your comment, and for BFG :) Great tool.

Comment: You're welcome - it's great to hear about people using The BFG!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git filter-repo --path fileToRemove --invert-paths`?

Comment: @MichelJung Thank you. That was a typo. I have edited the answer accordingly.